# Trying to plot multiple bar charts together using plt.subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, subplot

I have three bar charts that I have created. I would like to plot them all together using the fig, ax = plt.subplots function that is very popular. I can not get them to plot correctly together, but I can get them to show individually when I run each line below seperately

```
ax1 = buyreturns['return30'].plot.bar(grid=True, color=(buyreturns['return30'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))
ax2 = buyreturns['return60'].plot.bar(grid=True, color=(buyreturns['return60'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))
ax3 = buyreturns['return90'].plot.bar(grid=True, color=(buyreturns['return90'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}), legend = x)
```

I would like to get these to show up stacked on top of one another using the fig, ax = plt.subplots function.

I have tried the following code and the visual that is returned is an amalgamation of all the three barcharts, see the first picture below

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) =  plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=False, sharey= False, figsize=(24,16)) 

ax1 = buyreturns['return30'].plot.bar(grid=True, color=(buyreturns['return30'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))
ax2 = buyreturns['return60'].plot.bar(grid=True, color=(buyreturns['return60'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))
ax3 = buyreturns['return90'].plot.bar(grid=True, color=(buyreturns['return90'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}), legend = x)

plt.show()
```

I have also tried this following code and it returns what is in the second picture.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) =  plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=False, sharey= False, figsize=(24,16)) 

ax1.bar(len(buyreturns), buyreturns['return30'], bar_width, color=(buyreturns['return30'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))
ax2.bar(len(buyreturns), buyreturns['return60'], bar_width, color=(buyreturns['return60'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))
ax3.bar(len(buyreturns), buyreturns['return90'], bar_width, color=(buyreturns['return90'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))

plt.show()
```

Any input on how to fix these issues and return a 3 barchart graph would be great! Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ax=<the reference to your axes>` in the call to [`plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) =  plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=False, sharey= False, figsize=(24,16)) 

buyreturns['return30'].plot.bar(grid=True, color=(buyreturns['return30'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}), ax=ax1)
buyreturns['return60'].plot.bar(grid=True, color=(buyreturns['return60'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}), ax=ax2)
buyreturns['return90'].plot.bar(grid=True, color=(buyreturns['return90'] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}), ax=ax3)
```

Comment: Also, drop the `ax1 = ...` assignement. It is harmless if you know what it does (it reassigns the same axes object to the variable), but I suspect the OP asked the question because they do not know and somehow thought it would control the chosen axes.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Diziet's answer, but more *programmatic*:

```
fig, axes =  plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=False, sharey= False, figsize=(24,16)) 

# range(30,91,30) represents (30,60,90)
for i, ax in zip(range(30,91,30), axes):
    col_name = f'return{i}'
    colors = (buyreturns[col_name] > 0).map({True: 'g', False: 'r'})
    buyreturns[col_name].plot.bar(grid=True, 
                                  color=colors,
                                  ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Well received, thanks. Could you explain the range 'range(30,91,30) represents (30,60,90)'?

Comment: That is `for i in range(30,91,30)` will loop over `i=30, 60, 90`.